# What is the sum operation on torsors induced by Weil uniformization?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, geometric-langlands

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $G$ a reductive group, and $C$ a curve. The algebraic version of the Weil uniformization theorem (see e.g. arXiv:1511.06271v2) says that groupoid of $G$-torsors over $C$ is naturally equivalent to the groupoid of $C$-adelic $G$-automorphic forms. Notice that, once we pass to the quotient, the latter of these is naturally a group. In the case that $k=\mathbb{C}$, for instance, this is just the ordinary vector space structure on automorphic forms. This means that there is correspondingly a natural addition on (isomorphism classes of) $G$-torsors over $C$. Does this addition admit a nice description?

(Incidentally, I'm also interested in the dual question: in the case that $G=GL_n$, how do the sum and tensor product of vector bundles transfer over to automorphic forms? This must, of course, include all $n$ at once since the sum of rank $n$ and $m$ vector bundles is of rank $n+m$.)

Comment: Sum and tensor product of vector bundles do not stay at a single $GL_n$, rather they act from $(GL_m,GL_n)$ to $GL_{m+n}$ and $GL_{mn}$ respectively

Comment: Also, could you please provide details about Weil uniformization in this context? I could not find anything relevant in the literature.

Comment: I agree about the sum not being on a single n—I'll add that to the question. As for Weil uniformization, the form I'm using is stated in arXiv:1511.06271v2.

Comment: I think you are misreading Theorem 0.1 of that paper. The groupoid of $G$-torsors is not identified with any groupoid of automorphic forms, but with the groupoid quotient of the set $G(\mathbb{A})/G(\mathbb{O})$ by the left action of $G(F)$.

Comment: You're quite correct @JesseSilliman. I think that answers the question. Feel free to post this as an answer, else I will so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Jesse Silliman in the comments, this question is ill-posed. In fact, adelic automorphic forms are global sections of the structure sheaf of the moduli of $G$-torsors, not elements of this stack.